# 3DES_ECB decryption

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to decrypt data received from 3rd party server, using `3DES_DEC_ECB`
They have provided output also but I am not able to reproduce same.

```
Key = 5E8B6E1998F421204C6576544FE1A26B44FC775982D8CE2E
InputData = 13E37073120A47D119E82545CAAF1505E3E94E5E7D8B52F3
expectedoutput = 7CB842D42F4BA3C26C8297F5B26001FB5C9FD31532CA1CB7
techniqueActual output_data=3DES_DEC_ECB(Key, InputData)
```

I tried in below code but not success

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import util.HexString;

public class Util {
public static void main(String ...x) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,         
NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException{
String keydata=  "5E8B6E1998F421204C6576544FE1A26B44FC775982D8CE2E";

String inputData = "13E37073120A47D119E82545CAAF1505E3E94E5E7D8B52F3";

byte[] keyByte = new BigInteger(keydata,16).toByteArray();

SecretKeySpec key=new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "DESede");    

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");

c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] output = c.doFinal(inputData.getBytes());

String hexStr = HexString.bytesToHexString(output);
System.out.println("Decoded value : "+hexStr);

} }
```

Comment: i am getting below output =744042D5E571E84B05F60352D5052F58471635D51B8805057622F5BE9CA50F9B991C235332F9FD5A5B50207B49F003BB

Comment: In your sample, you print `x`, as hex. But `x` isn't defined in the code. What is it? You should be able to include a [mcve].

Comment: x is output byte array

Comment: And `data` is ...? I think if you take a very close look at this missing variable, you will find your problem. Posting a true [mcve] instead of a rough approximation of your code saves everyone time.

Comment: attached running code

Comment: Thank you! Now look at the input to `c.doFinal()`. You are not hex-decoding the bytes first. You should first decode each byte in the input string from hexadecimal to a byte. That's why your output is twice the expected length.

Comment: Agree with @erickson.  FYI triple Des in ECB mode is an insecure algorithm in an insecure mode.  If the amount of data is not large, triple des may still be okay, but ECB mode is never okay.  Having said that, I understand you may have no control over it: if whoever is providing the data is encrypting it an insecure way, then yes you have to decrypt it that way too.

Comment: Its working, Thanks @erickson,@TheGreatContini